# Implementing log4net in REST API written in .Net Core 6.0

Tags: rest, .net-core, log4net

I need to add logging to a REST API.  It is written in .NET Core and will be run on .Net Core 6.0.  I created a log4net.config file as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler"/>
      </configSections>
      <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
          <param name="File" value="C:\CMApps\Log\CMS.Folder.API.MyApp.txt" />
          <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
          <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
          <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="50000KB" />
          <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
          <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
          </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
          <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root>
        <logger name="MyApp" additivity="false">
          <level value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </logger>    
      </log4net>  
    </configuration>
```

Googling around said to add builder with

```
var builder = WebApplication.builder
```

in the Program.cs - but WebApplication was unknown to my app
so I used the following in the Program.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
            // added this
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
            });
```

my controller has this

```
        namespace SecureVault.Controllers
        {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("API/[controller]/{id?}")]
    
        public class MyAppController : ControllerBase
        {
            //  private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
          (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
             log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyApp");
    
            [HttpGet]
            public string Get(int id)
            {
                log.Info("remove before Production");
    
                return id.ToString();
            }
```

when I look at the log object - no Appenders
what do I need to do to get it to work

Comment: figured it out - edit the log4net.config removing the <?xml line, configuration and configSections so only the <log4net> to </log4net> remains

Answer (score 0):

log4net should be just the  element

```
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:\CMApps\Log\CMS.BaseTech.API.SecureVault.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="50000KB" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

this line in the controller

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
             log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyApp");
```

should instead be

```
        private readonly ILogger<MyAppController> _logger;
        public MyAppController(ILogger<MyAppController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("remove before production - Info");
            _logger.LogDebug("remove before production - Debug");
            _logger.LogWarning("remove before production - Warning");
            _logger.LogError("remove before production - Error");
        }
```